# 1 positional argument but 2 were given GlueContext split rows DynamicFrameCollection

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I have this code to get data from a table and split it using a certain field

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "mydb", table_name = "mytable")

collection=df.split_rows({"split_field": {"=": "value"}},"dfSplit","dfOthers")
print("Collection keys: "+str(list(collection.keys())[0]))
print("Colleciton splitted values: "+str(collection.values(collection.keys())))
print("Colleciton splitted values: "+str(collection.values('dfSplit')))
```

I tried a set of options to print the values under one of the dataframes in the collection. Despite seeing the keys that I setted up, I am not able to read the values.
I tried in differents runs the last two rows.
But both returns:

```
Keys take 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I think this error is related to create an instance of the object, but I don't understand why should be created when values is a function as `keys` is, and the `keys` funciton works in the print and doesn't return an error.

I am using this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-collection.html), but only says that values function -->  Returns a list of the DynamicFrame values in this collection.

Comment: Have you tried `collection.values()` with no arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to @blackbishop I found a solution

```
myCollection=new.values()
df=list(myCollection)[0]
```

Using these lines I have been able to get the vañues of the DynamicFrameCollection. Then turning these to a list, and indexing to the first one I get the results filtered using the split method.